# Upgrade Ubuntu next to windows

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, windows-7

On my Pc are two systems, Win 7 and Ubuntu 13.10
Now I want to upgrade Ubuntu on Version 14.04, now I wonder if it's totally ok, if I pick the installation option "upgrade Ubuntu 13.10 to Ubuntu 14.04", or if this could kill my Windows partition.
Normally i would have pick "something else" and installed it per hand, but now i would like to keep my personal stuff from Ubuntu.
thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said upgrading your ubuntu will not break or touch you windows.

The only problem you may have is is grub update fails which is very unlikely and easily fixable.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading Ubuntu will not touch your Windows partition.